# Automatic Reference Counting and finalize

Tags: ios, automatic-ref-counting

Quick question: I use lots of NSObject derived classes and am wondering how to properly cleanup class properties that may own instances of other classes (in the snippet below this is an array of custom class instances). Is my usage of `new` and `finalize` below correct?

My understanding is that `new` is a convenience method that calls both alloc and init, and `finalize` gets called before `dealloc` - at least this is what I have gleaned from reading the docs. Do I have this right?

Thanks for any tips/best practices, etc!

```
- (id)new {
waffleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:kCellCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < kCellCount;  i++) {
        WaffleCell * cell = [WaffleCell new];
        [waffleArray addObject:cell];
     }

    return self;
}

// clean up
- (void)finalize {

    [waffleArray removeAllObjects];
     waffleArray = nil;

    [super finalize];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` on `NSObject` is a class method, not an instance method as you have it. Also I don't really see why you'd overload `new`. It would be more common to overload `init` so something like this:

```
- (id)init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        waffleArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:kCellCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < kCellCount;  i++) {
            WaffleCell * cell = [WaffleCell new];
            [waffleArray addObject:cell];
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

As for `finalize`, you really don't need to do that. This is what Apple says about it:

> The garbage collector invokes this method on the receiver before disposing of the memory it uses. When garbage collection is enabled, this method is invoked instead of dealloc.

With ARC enabled you wouldn't need to do anything and since the garbage collector will not be running anyway, `finalize` won't get called anyway. ARC will automatically generate code which will `release` `waffleArray` in `dealloc` for you, which is enough for proper memory management in this case because `waffleArray`'s retain count will then drop to 0, be deallocated itself which will go and release the objects in the array.

Comment: OK - thanks. I don't think I understand the distinction between class and instance methods - will have to read up.

Comment: A class method can be thought of as similar to a static method in other languages like Java and C++. There is no "self" in that context and is denoted by a `+` at the start of the method signature rather than a `-`.

Comment: Also, just to be clear: ARC is not garbage collection, and will never invoke -finalize under any circumstances.

Comment: @Catfish_Man indeed. Fair point to mention that. I'll edit to be clearer that it won't get called anyway.